# Can I specify a point and get all features within a certain radius of this point?

Tags: qgis, feature-extraction

I have recently shifted to QGIS from ArcGIS and am looking for some help/pointers with the following:

Does QGIS have a method by which I can specify a lat-lon coordinate (or a utm x,y coordinates, coordinate system not imp), and get all features that lie within a certain radius of this point?

I downloaded the 3rd party plugins for QGIS and after looking through all of them, didn't find anything with this functionality (though I could have very well not understood something completely). I am considering writing a plugin in case something doesn't already exist

Edit: I looked at the option under: View -> Select -> Select Features By Radius. This seems to be similar in concept to what I am aiming to do (except that the center needs to be specified).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a plugin. But if you want to develop it, you will find the source code of "Select Features By Radius" in the "Select Plus" plugin. It should be quite simple to add an input form for entering coordinates and radius instead of specifying them by mouse.

Comment: That is the approach I am taking as the select by radius is an excellent starting point. 
I was initially looking in the source under src->app->qgsmaptoolselectradius.h. But modifying the plugin under Select Plus would be a lot easier and quicker.
Thanks for the suggestion.